# Force close for Android Custom Camera app

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

I am developing an android custom camera application without using the intent (to avoid getting android's built in camera features). I have enabled auto focus feature in my app. I am taking the picture on press of a keyVolume Button.  And I am using the below code for setting the parameters.

```
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);
    p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    camera.setParameters(p1);
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpgCallback);


    void setHandler(Handler autoFocusHandler, int autoFocusMessage) 
    {
           this.autoFocusHandler = autoFocusHandler;
           this.autoFocusMessage = autoFocusMessage;
    }

    private AutoFocusCallback autoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback() 
    {
         private Object success;
         @Override
         public void onAutoFocus(boolean autoFocusSuccess, Camera camera)
         {  
              if (autoFocusHandler != null)
              {
                    Message message = autoFocusHandler.obtainMessage(autoFocusMessage, success);
                    autoFocusHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, AUTOFOCUS_INTERVAL_MS);
                    autoFocusHandler = null;
              }
              else
              {

              }
         }
};
```

But the problem is that, this code works fine only for LG phone. and i am getting force close on all other phones after running it.

And the Error Log looks like this

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=kOc9G

Not getting where i am going wrong. Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: This is a good start on the question, but please post all relevant information (like the error log) inline.

Comment: go through the below link http://ankitha-androiddevelopment.blogspot.in/

Comment: I have posted the error log!

Answer (score 2):

Different phones have different camera params. Check if mode available befire actually setting it.

For example, in your case there is `public List<String> getSupportedFocusModes ()` function of 
`Camera.Parameters` class.

Afaik, cheap phones like acer or zte or some others, have very weak programming support for their cameras.

UPD: code sample

```
    Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
    List<String> modes = p.getSupportedFocusModes();
    if(modes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
    {
        p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback);

    }
    else
    {
        // this is default focus mode if autofocus unsupported.
        // also, we should not call camera.autoFocus(autoFocusCallback) here
        p.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
        camera.setParameters(p);
    }
```

Comment: In addition to @Raiv's suggestion, I would recommend to use `try {} catch` around Camera.setParameters() because there are too many different devices with their crazy incompatible cameras.

Comment: Could u please post how to implement getSupportedFocusModes() method in the code? @Raiv

Comment: I used the try catch block around Camera.setParameters. But After taking the picture, the camera preview doesn't restart for taking the next pic. I need to open the app again to take the next pic. @Alex Cohn

Answer (score 1):

you are using

```
 Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
```

so replace

```
 camera.setParameters(p1);
```

with

```
 camera.setParameters(p);
```

I think this should help you....

```
Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
List<Size> sizes = p.getSupportedPictureSizes();
// Choose any one you want among sizes
size = sizes.get(0);
p.setPictureSize(size.width, size.height);
camera.setParameters(p);
```

Comment: I have used camera.setParameters(p). Still the same problem!!

Comment: no..My mean to say that right now same error occured as at set parameteres?

Comment: When did you have created a object for Camera??

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "p.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);" line.

By default focus mode will be FOCUS_MODE_AUTO.